# Where do I put the request data?

Tags: sql-injection, mysql

Now, I understand this might not be the right place to post about Acunetix but I'm searching my site for any exploits and a couple of SQL Injection exploits have shown up on a /Profile page, how would I be able to see the issue through my own browser (i.e. See the SQL error through my own browser instead of the Acunetix browser.)

Request Data

```
bf=2&fm=1%27%22&os=1&update=Save&user=%7busername%7d
```

Answer (score 0):

If it’s a simple HTTP GET request, you can just append to the URI with an `?`. If it’s HTTP POST, you could write a mockup form and submit it:

```
<form action="…" method="POST">
  <input name="bf" value="2">
  <input name="fm" value="1'&quot;">
  <input name="os" value="1">
  <input name="update" value="Save">
  <input name="user" value="{username}">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Or try to identify the original form on your site and change the *fm* value to `1'"`. If the value of *fm* cannot be changed via the GUI, your web browser’s developer tools may help you.